# Suspiciously slow global memory access in CUDA

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, global

I have a small CUDA kernel, which behaves very suspiciously. The kernel processes a single point in each thread, and compares it to a large dataset. Based on this dataset, an indicator is computed and saved to the output:

```
 __global__ void distanceKernel(float4*__restrict__  data, float4* __restrict__ points, float* __restrict__ output, unsigned int numdata, unsigned int numpoints) {
 //Read the threadID
 const int col = threadIdx.x;

 //Value to be computed
 float indicator=0.0f;

 //Loads the specific point
 float4 const point_p = points[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];

 //Stream all the data from global memory to shared memory
 for (size_t round = 0; round < (numdata+ BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / (BLOCK_SIZE); ++round) {

     __shared__ float4 sData[BLOCK_SIZE * 3];

     sData[col * 3] = data[BLOCK_SIZE*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING*round + (col)*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING];
     sData[col * 3 + 1] = data[BLOCK_SIZE*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING*round + (col)*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING + 1];
     sData[col * 3 + 2] = data[BLOCK_SIZE*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING*round + (col)*CUDA_FACE_OFFSETTING + 2];

     __syncthreads();
     for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
         //... Lots of computations ...
     }
     __syncthreads();
 }
 //Write out the data
 output[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = indicator;}
```

The code works correctly, the results are perfect. My problem is, that the last line seems to be too slow (very very slow), although it should coalesce. With the last line the execution time is 31.5 seconds (64 block & 64 threads). However, when removing it, the execution time is only 0.2 s. Measurement was done using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, calling it before starting the kernel and after cudaDeviceSynchronize().

Does anybody has any idea, why it could be that slow? The last memory access does not seem to be very different from reading the variable point_p at the beginning of the code. Also, numdata is large, which means that reading many hundreds of MB data is much faster, than writing a single value back...

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: All you are seeing is the effect of compiler optimisation. This question has been asked many times before here. When I find a suitable example, I will close this as a duplicate

Comment: Can you give a link to the original question, where a detailed answer was given?